# Shopify discount code specific message to be displayed

Tags: html, shopify

I want to apply discount code specific messages on the shopify email templates. I tried the following code, it's showing me error - "Liquid error: Unknown operator = " in the purchase email which I receive.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left-column">
        {% if discounts %}Discount (code: {{ discounts.first.code }})
    </div>                   

    <div class="right-column">
        {{ discounts_savings | money_with_currency }}
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div class="left-column">
        {% for discount in discounts %}
            {% if discount.first.code = "DISCODE-2015" %} 
                Your $50 amazon.com gift card will be send to you soon!
            {% endif %}                   
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `=`, but it should be `==`. [See here](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/operators#basic-operators).

I think you also want `discount.code` where you have `discount.first.code`.

Try replacing this line:

```
{% if discount.first.code = "DISCODE-2015" %}
```

with this:

```
{% if discount.code == "DISCODE-2015" %}
```

Comment: I had tried using the code {% if discount.code == "DISCODE-2015" %} it is still giving me the error "Liquid error: Unknown operator = "

Comment: @user3286560 I just tested the code you provided with the changes I suggested and it is working fine for me in the Order Confirmation email template. Perhaps the error is being caused by something else.